# Concatenate percent field

Tags: formula-field

How can I concatenate in formula field 2 percent custom fields? I use this formula to

```
VALUE(TEXT(percent__c)) VALUE(TEXT(percent1__c))
```

The result: 10% + 20%?

Is it possible?

Comment: The formula field must be a text type and you could then do TEXT(percent__c) & text(other field). Not really sure though what you are looking for as your question is unclear

Comment: I need join two fields in one. I have two fields percent, so I need join in just on field like,
percent__c=10%
percent2__c=20%
Joinpercent__c= 10% 20%
"concatenate" the old fields.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text(field1*100) & "% " & text(field2*100) & "%"
```

This should output 10% 20%, given those inputs. The & symbol is used for concatenation of text.